# asp c# basic mailto function

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have been trying to go the next line using '\n' similarly used in Java but it doesn't seem to work in this script.

'\n' doesn't work but the entire function does without it.

My question is how do you you go to the next line?

```
    String text_name = Text_Name.Text;
    String text_email = Text_Email.Text;
    String text_message = Text_Message.Text;

    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "mailto",

       "<script type = 'text/javascript'>parent.location='mailto:" + "someone@gmail.com" +

       "?subject=" + "Inquiry" +

       "&body=" + 

       "Contact Name: " + text_name + '\n' +

       "Contact By: " + text_email + '\n' +

       "Inquiry: " + text_message + '\n' +

       "'</script>");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Environment.NewLine` instead of `'\n'`.

Comment: Coded this way "Environment.NewLine"?

Answer (score 0):

Use **Environment.NewLine** instead of **\n**:

```
"Contact Name: " + text_name + Environment.NewLine +
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using '\r\n' instead of '\n'.
Or you may also use 'Environment.NewLine'

```
MessageBox.Show("Line 1" + Environment.NewLine + "Line 2");
```

or

```
MessageBox.Show("Line 1\r\nLine2", "BlahBlah", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put %0A for new line in mailto